# Is there a way to check if a variable's value is the same as another's?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to make a password system, but I don't know the password. Whatever the password is, it is contained in a variable. I am trying:

```
<input type="password" id="pass"> 
<button onclick="pass()">Go</button>
<script>
var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
var answer = "the password"
function pass() {
if (password == answer) {
window.location.replace("http://example.com");
}
else {
document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password. Try again?</p>";
}
}
</script>
```

and it didn't work. Is there a way to check if a variable's value is the same as another's?
Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById("pass").value;` you need to read that inside the `pass()` function. Because you want to get the value _at the time the button is clicked_. Currently, it reads the value at the moment the script is read, i.e. at the loading of the page, when there is probably nothing in your textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a "timing" issue : you should read the value of the user input at the moment the button is clicked, yo you need to move your `var password = document.getElementById("pass").value` line into the function call.

```js
const answer = "the password";
function pass() {
  const password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (password == answer) {
    document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "<p>Good password!</p>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password. Try again?</p>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="pass"> 
<button onclick="pass()">Go</button>
<div id="note"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value of the input inside the function as follows:

```js
var answer = "the password"
function pass() {
     var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
     if (password == answer) 
          window.location.replace("http://example.com");
     else 
          document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password. Try again?</p>";
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="pass" /> 
<button onclick="pass()">Go</button>
<div id="note"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are same mistakes, try this

```
var answer = "the password";
function pass() {
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    if (password === answer) {
        window.location.replace("http://example.com");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password. Try again?</p>";
    }
}
```